# is it possible to use nao_ctrl and choregraphe simultaneously?

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is not possible out of the box, can you suggest some code changes / a high-level approach?

My desired task is to teleoperate the limbs (with nao_ctrl and openni_nao), while having Choregraphe do face recognition and attention / gaze servoing with the head.

Thanks for any tips!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11002/is-it-possible-to-use-nao_ctrl-and-choregraphe-simultaneously?/) by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on ROS Answers with karma: 481 on 2011-08-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no reason why it shouldn't work, as long as you don't try to do conflicting things (but I don't know in detail how openni_nao is communicating with ROS / NaoQI). In fact, you can even connect nao_ctrl to the simulated Nao running in Choregraphe (use the correct port and IP 127.0.0.1 for NaoQI).

Of course, if you start changing Nao's leg joint angles in Choregraphe while he's walking with nao_ctrl you will produce a fall in the worst case - in the best case NaoQI won't even let you control it or will stop the walk. Same for the head: if you do gaze servoing then just don't try to change the head angles at the same time with teleoperation.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2011-08-30**:
PS - if I get the error above, I can get back in business by: closing (and disconnecting from robot) Choregraphe and nao_ctrl, then running nao_ctrl, then running Choregraphe and connecting it to robot

**Comment by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) on 2011-08-29**:
Confirmed to work! A bit touchy, though... I sometimes get the error: "Address already in use"
Could not create Proxy to "ALMotion".
Desc: 'Port not free. Another broker is using this port.'
Overall, seems to work better if I have nao_ctrl running first, then open Choregraphe.  THANKS!